# Checking when quotient of polynomials is integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, problem-solving, factoring

I'm learning some elementary number theory, and seek integers $n$ for which $\frac{n^3 - 3n^2 + 4}{2n-1}$ is an integer. My instinct was to let such an integer be denoted by $k$ and get the condition $n^3 - 3n^2 - 2kn + (4+k)=0$ then try to factorize to get a condition on $n$. However, I couldn't see how to factorise. In the solutions, instead, they start by observing that multiplying the fraction by $8$ means its still an integer, and seeing that $8 \cdot \frac{n^3 - 3n^2 + 4}{2n-1} = 4n^2 - 10n -5 + \frac{27}{2n-1}$ and checking when $2n-1$ divides $27$. My question is: why was my instinct to factorize incorrect, and how on Earth would one think to observe that multipling by *eight* still gives an integer. I understand their solution, I'm particularly looking for motivation or a perspective that makes their approach obvious so I can apply similar techniques in future.

Comment: Idea is to do the long division between the two polynomials, which leaves a fraction with the remainder in the numerator, which is a constant. Multiplying by $8$ makes the calculations easier, but is not required.

Comment: And why is thinking to bash the long division a better idea than factorizing in the way I described? Because we literally can't factorize (easily) here?

Comment: Because you know you can always carry out the euclidean division, but you cannot factor arbitrary polynomials unless you are very very lucky.

Comment: @dxiv Yes, (polynomial) euclidean division (with remainder) is the key idea. This special case (division by a *linear* polynomial $\,x-c)\,$ is so important it has a name, viz. the Polynomial Remainder Theorem, i.e. $\,f(x)\bmod x-c = f(c).\,$ Choosing $\,c = 1/2\,$ then scaling to get *integer* divisibilities we can easily solve the OP, e.g. as in my answer.

Comment: **Beware** that $\,a\mid 8b\Rightarrow a\mid b\,$ is true $\iff (a,8)=1\iff (a,2)=1,\,$ i.e. $\,a\,$ is odd. Many arguments omit this crucial step (which is essential in the OP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm particularly looking for motivation or a perspective that makes their approach obvious so I can apply similar techniques in future.

Easy general way: $ $ via a $ $ *fractional* $ $ generalization of the polynomial remainder / factor  theorems. If $\,a,b,n,m\,$ are integers and $\,f(x)\,$ is a polynomial with *integer* coefficients then

$$\begin{align}\,n\!-\!a\mid f(n) &\iff \ \ n\!-\!a\mid f(a),\ \ \ {\rm by}\ \ \  f(n)\equiv f(a)\!\pmod{\!n\!-\!a}\\[.6em]
\leadsto\ \ bn\!-\!a\mid f(n) &\iff bn\!-\!a\mid b^k f\left(\frac{a}b\right),\ \ {\rm if}\ \ \color{#90f}{(a,b)=1},\ \ k\ge \deg f \end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

since $\,(bn\!-\!a,b) = \color{#90f}{(-a,b)}=1,\ $ so $\ bn\!-\!a\mid b^k m \iff bn\!-\!a\mid m,\,$ by Euclid's Lemma.

so $\,2n\!-\!1\mid n^3\!-\!3n^2\!+\!4 \iff \color{#0a0}{2n}\!-\!\color{#c00}1\mid 2^3(n^3\!-\!3n^2\!+\!4) = \underbrace{(\color{#0a0}{2n})^3\!-\!6(\color{#0a0}{2n})^2\!+\!32}_{\large\equiv\ \color{#c00}1^3-6(\color{#c00}1)^2+32\ \equiv\ 27}$

Comment: We used a *fraction-free* way to evaluate $\,b^k f(a/b)\,\bmod\, bn\!-\!a\,$ (I can elaborate if need be). $\ \ $

Comment: Don't you think this question is probably a duplicate, Bill?

Comment: @Gerry Maybe, but I didn't have any luck searching (and I spent quite some time). I need to figure out some better keywords to facilitate searching on problems like this.  If you know some good targets then please do share them. I'll delete this if I later find a good target (as I ususally do in cases like this).

Comment: Maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3714351/when-the-quotient-frac-13n2n2n2-is-an-integer ? But if you couldn't find one, it's probably not there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the fraction is an integer, the GCD of numerator and denominator is large....   the outcome of extended GCD is, after multiplying by 27,

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ 8 \left(   x^{3}  - 3 x^{2}  + 4 \right)   -  \left(  2 x  - 1 \right)  \left(   4 x^{2}  - 10 x  - 5   \right)  = 27  $$
then divide through by $(2x-1) $  to get to your $\frac{27}{2x-1}$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$  \left(   x^{3}  - 3 x^{2}  + 4 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  2 x  - 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{3}  - 3 x^{2}  + 4 \right)  =  \left(  2 x  - 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 4 x^{2}  - 10 x  - 5 }{ 8 }  \right) } +  \left( \frac{ 27}{8 } \right)  $$
$$  \left(  2 x  - 1 \right)  =  \left( \frac{ 27}{8 } \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 16 x  - 8 }{ 27 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$
$$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 4 x^{2}  - 10 x  - 5 }{ 8 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 4 x^{2}  - 10 x  - 5 }{ 8 }  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 16 x  - 8 }{ 27 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 8 x^{3}  - 24 x^{2}  + 32 }{ 27 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 16 x  - 8 }{ 27 }  \right) } $$
$$  \left(   x^{3}  - 3 x^{2}  + 4 \right)  \left( \frac{ 8}{27 } \right)  -  \left(  2 x  - 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 4 x^{2}  - 10 x  - 5 }{ 27 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$